# How to tell if I have TMC2208 or A4988 Drivers on Creality Silent V4.2.3 Board?

Tags: stepper-driver, creality

I have a new Creality Ender 2 Pro with a Creality 4.2.3 mainboard. I'm attempting to compile Marlin to fix a bug. How can I tell what driver chips I have on this board?

I've narrowed it down to likely `A4988` or `TMC2208_STANDALONE` or possibly the `TMC2225`. Strangely Creality only has documentation for the 4.2.2 and the 4.2.7 boards (not 4.2.3)

4.2.2 => TMC2208
4.2.3 => ?
4.2.7 => TMC2225

Some say you can tell the driver just by listening to the noise it makes. [Here is a video of the printer running](https://youtu.be/4hL-r02w6rM). The motors are nearly silent to my ear.

[image: Photo of Ender 2 Pro motherboard version 4.2.3]

[image: Top corner photo]

Resources

- https://github.com/Creality3DPrinting/Ender-3/issues/58#issuecomment-842935869
- 4.2.2 [schematic](https://github-repository-files.githubusercontent.com/139231738/7626788?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20211215%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20211215T153407Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=43dfe1ff5518c5003cf55ade1554caeb5953c733a599db07fb153cc976cebb45&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=139231738&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D1623133432-Creality422-Schematic-2.pdf&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf)
- [Marlin Config pull request](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Configurations/pull/633#issuecomment-995206382)

Comment: How could A4988 be an option for a "silent" board?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to ['The-EG' comment](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Configurations/pull/633#issuecomment-995206382) in this GitHub issue, [Add Creality Ender 2 Pro config #633](https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Configurations/pull/633), you can often determine the stepper drivers by one of a few ways:

1. Listen to the sound. The 'TMC22**' will sound much quieter
2. Look for a marking in Sharpie on the SD Card reader

   ```
   C = HR4998
   E = A4988
   A = TMC2208
   B = TMC2209
   H = TMC2225
   ```
3. Remove the heat sync

   https://github.com/MarlinFirmware/Configurations/pull/633#issuecomment-995480295

   After removing the heat sync, it appears that the Chip is actually a `MS35775`

   [image: Closeup of MS35775 on board]

Comment: Indeed! And, as far as Marlin is concerned the TMC2225 and TMC2208 are the same, so it's *hopefully* a matter of 2208/25 vs 2209. Unless Creality did something completely off the wall...

Comment: Of which known driver is this a clone?

Answer (score 1):

MS35775 appears to be TMC208 compatible.  You can find the data sheet on relmon.com here is the overview:

- 2-Phase stepping motor peak current of 2A
- Step / dir interface 2, 4, 8, 16, or 32 microstep
- Internal 256 micro steps
- Quiet mode
- Fast mode
- HS Rdson 0.29 Ω ,LS Rdson 0.28 Ω
- Voltage range 4.75 ~ 36V
- When the motor is still, it will enter into the power saving mode automatically
- Internal resistor mode is optional (no need for external sense resistor)
- Single wire UART bus and OTP control
- QFN28 package